# MS SQL Восстановление таблицы из бэкапа

Tags: sql, sql-server, резервное-копирование, таблицы

Существует ли способ восстановления одной таблицы, без рестора всей БД? Модель восстановления полная, бэкапы лога есть. Бэкапы не сжатые. Версия MS SQL 2016.

Comment: Нет, нету. Поднимите бэкап рядом на том же сервере, и перекиньте данные между базами.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Встроенными средствам SQL Server или бесплатно к сожалению нельзя. Но с помощью сторонних утилит это можно сделать.

1. [Litespeed](https://www.quest.com/products/litespeed-for-sql-server/). Стоит в районе 1000$. Есть пробная версия на 15 дней. Два ограничения при работе с нативными бэкапами - не умеет делать восстановление таблиц если бэкап сжат (compressed) или зашифрован (encrypted).
2. [RedGate SQL Backup](https://www.red-gate.com/products/dba/sql-backup/). Стоит 1070$. Есть пробная версия на 30 дней. Также не умеет работать с нативными бэкапами если они сжаты (compressed) или зашифрованы (encrypted).

Есть еще [Поэтапное восстановление (SQL Server)](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/piecemeal-restores-sql-server) - встроенный механизм, но он требует заранее вынесенной в отдельную файловую группу таблицу и специального типа бэкапа.